# Unable to insert data in WMI Class "DateTime" property

Tags: powershell, wmi, datetime-format

I am declaring property "InstallDate" in WMI class as below:

```
$newClass.Properties.Add("InstallDate",[System.Management.CimType]::DateTime, $false)
$newClass.Properties["InstallDate"].Qualifiers.Add("Key", $true)
```

Then I am getting InstallDate from registry using below cmdlet:

```
$Win10Upgrade = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\System\Setup\Source* | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::$_} | Select @{n="InstallDate"; e={([DateTime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($_.InstallDate)}}
```

And then I am trying to insert it into WMI class CM_Win10UpgradeHistory into declared "InstallDate" property.

```
Set-WmiInstance -Class CM_Win10UpgradeHistory -Namespace ROOT\CustomSCCMInventory -Arguments @{InstallDate=$Win10Upgrade.InstallDate} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
```

Raw value of InstallDate from registry is "1573146514"
DateTime Operation in powershell changes it to "11/7/2019 5:08:34 PM"

But I am getting error of "Set-WmiInstance : Type mismatch".
Also I tried inserting raw value as well, but it's also giving the same error. I am able to insert it if I declass WMI class property value as "String" but not as "DateTime"

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found it.
For inserting value in "DateTime" property, it needs to be converted to

```
$OSInstallDate = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime($Win10Upgrade.InstallDate)
```

And then $OSInstallDate can be feeded to DateTime property.